# Question regarding the "Tell, don't Ask" idea

Tags: c#, java, oop

There is this famous quote that says

> Procedural code gets information then
>   makes decisions. Object-oriented code
>   tells objects to do things.  — Alec
>   Sharp

The subject of the post is precisely about that.

Let's assume we are developing a game in which we have a `Game` where there is a `Board`.
When facing the problem of deciding which methods are we going to implement on the `Board` class, I always think of two different ways:

### The first approach is to

populate the `Board` class with `getSize()`, `getPieceAt(x, y)`, `setPieceAt(x, y, piece)`. This will seem reasonable and is what is generally found in libraries/frameworks. The `Board` class has a set of internal features that wants to share and has a set of methods that will allow the client of the class to control the class as he wishes. The client is supposed to ask for the things he needs and to decide what to do. If he wants to set all board pieces to black, he will "manually" iterate over them to accomplish that goal.

### The second approach is about

looking for `Board`'s dependent classes, and see what they are "telling" it to do. `ClassA` wants to count how many pieces are red, so I'd implement a `calculateNumberOfRedPieces()`. `ClassB` intends to clear all the pieces on the `Board`(set all of them to `NullPiece`, for example), so I'd add a `clearBoard()` method to the `Board` class. This approach is less general, but allows for a lot more flexibility on other aspects. If I "hide" `Board` behind an `IBoard` interface, and decide that I'd want to have a board with infinite size, doing in the first way, I'd be stuck, as I'd have to iterate over an infinite number of items! On the other hand, in this way, I could do fine (I could, for instance, assume all pieces are null other than the ones contained in a hashtable!).

### So...

I am aware that if I intend to make a library, I am probably stuck with the first approach, as it is way more general. On the other hand, I'd like to know which approach to follow when I am in total control of the system that'll make use of the `Board` class -- when I am the one who is going to also design all the classes that'll make use of the `Board`. Currently, and in the future (won't the second approach raise problems if later I decide to add new classes that are dependent on the `Board` with different "desires"?).

Comment: He's asking what makes more sense. Option 1, Option 2, Option 3 (Something else)

Comment: I don't get how (common) "object-orient" code is not just procedural code with objects.

Comment: @pst. What you said is very true, at the top level there is always a main function that is called, plus there are static methods. However, the goal of OO design is to remove as much of the procedural code as possible, making them more manageable objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quote is really warning you away from data structures that don't do anything with the data they hold. So your Board class in the first approach might be able to be done away with and replaced by a generic collection.

Regardless, the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) still applies, so you need to treat the second approach with caution.

What I would do is invoke YAGNI (you aren't gonna need it) and try to see how far I could go using a generic collection rather than a Board class. If you find that later you do need the Board class its responsibility will likely be much more clear by then.

Comment: -1 I disagree. YAGNI isn't that simple, imho. The approach you are describing _may_ work for very small projects with a single developer only, however it will fail miserably even if there is one additional developer, because when working in a team you will rather sooner than later have to agree on _some_ kind of architecture, and you can most certainly not say "nah, this didn't work, lets add some classes here and there" after a few weeks of development. YAGNI is about keeping it simple, not about starting to run blindly and then return to the beginning if you went the wrong way!

Comment: The core idea behind YAGNI is to defer the making of decisions as late as possible so that when you actually have to take those decisions you have the best information available to you to inform those decisions. Of course the team environment will influence when decisions need to be taken. Personally, I've found that the critical decision point happens a lot later than many people expect.

Comment: To cite [this source](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?YouArentGonnaNeedIt): "This doesn't mean you should avoid building flexibility into your code. It means you shouldn't overengineer something based on what you think you might need later on."
However I think that this is exactly what you'd be doing if you decided to model the `Board` as a generic collection: Giving up a vast amount of flexibility, meaning you may have to rewrite lots of code later on.

Comment: C2 is a great resource that I recommend everyone have a look at at some stage. But YAGNI is somewhat contentious even there, so it's certainly beyond my abilities to provide a canonical interpretation here.

Comment: The `Board` object with its getters and setters and no game-related logic is already adhering to the SRP: its responsibility is to show that the data it holds goes together on a board. Putting business logic in it would violate SRP. I would call the `Board` class a data structure that you ask for data instead of telling it what to do with the data. Every system at some point needs those data structures.

Answer (score 1):

Let me offer the contrarian point of view. I think the second approach has legs. I agree with the single responsibility principle, but it seems to me that there's a defensible single mission/concern for a `Board` class: Maintaining the playing field.

I can imagine a very reasonable set of methods such as `getSize()`, `getPiece(x,y)`, `setPiece(x, y, color)`, `removePiece(x, y)`, `movePiece(x1,y1,x2,y2)`,  `clear()`, `countPieces(color)`, `listPiecePositions(color)`, `read(filename)`, `write(filename)`, etc. that have a congent and clear shared mission. The handling of those board-management concerns in an abstracted way would allow other classes to implement game logic more cleanly, and for either `Board` or `Game` to be more readily extended in the future.

YAGNI is all well and good, but my understanding is that it urges you to not start building beautiful edifices with the hope that one day they'll be usefully occupied. For example, I wouldn't spend any time working toward the future possibility of an infinite playing surface, a 3D playing surface, or a playing surface that can be embedded onto a sphere. If I wanted to take YAGNI very seriously, I wouldn't write even straightforward `Board` methods until they were needed.

But that doesn't mean I would discard Board as a conceptual organization or possible class. And it certainly doesn't mean that I wouldn't put any thought at all into how to separate concerns in my program. At least YAGNI in my world doesn't require you start with the lowest-level data structures, little or nothing by way of encapsulation, and a completely procedural approach.

I disagree with the notion that the first approach is more general (in any useful way), or what appears to the the consensus that one should "just see how far you can get without abstracting anything." Honestly, that sounds like how we solved [eight queens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle). In 1983. In Pascal.

YAGNI is a great guiding principle that helps avoid a lot of [second system effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-system_effect) and similar bottoms-up, we-can-do-it-so-we-should mistakes. But YAGNI that's crossed the [Agile Practice Stupidity Threshold](http://www.skorks.com/2009/08/does-yagni-mean-you-ignore-the-obvious/) is *not* a virtue.

Answer (score 0):

CurtainDog is right, invoke Yagni and figure out what you actually need right now, implement that, then make sure it's not going to prevent any features that may be desirable in the future.

The second approach violates the principle that superclasses should not know about each of its subclasses. I think the element you're missing is that the base class can define template methods, like getBoardSize, countRedPieces, countBlackPieces, that can be overridden by subclasses and your superclass has code that uses those template methods, therefore telling its subclasses what to do, but not how to do it.